# background: url(), background-image: url() is not working

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want to make an image button with HTML and CSS. So I tried `background:url()` but it's not working. I also tried these:

1. `background: url(res/play.png)`
2. `background: url("res/play.png")`
3. `background: url("/res/play.png")`
4. `background: url(/res/play.png)`
5. `background-image: url(res/play.png)`

They all not working. This is my directory structure.

```
MyProgram
└ res directory
└ style.css
└ index.html
```

This is my code. The image is in `res` directory.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="previousButton"></button>
      <button id="playButton"></button>
      <button id="nextButton"></button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="range" id="volumeSlider" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="1">
      <button id="muteButton"></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```css
button#playButton {
  background: url(res/play.png);
}
```

[image: the output]

Comment: What is the filesystem layout of your website? Are you only using static files? Please post a screenshot of how it is currently rendered. What requests are visible in your browser's Developer Tools' Network tab?

Comment: @Dai Thanks for comment. I posted my result screen.

Comment: make sure your pathing is correct, try to render it with an `img` tag.

Comment: not sure, but please try this `background:  url(../res/play.png);`

Comment: I don't understand why you are listing it as a `background` element, but... IMHO, your `background-color: purple;` is covering your `<button>` up - essentially hiding it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try adding width and height.
The background itself is not content, therefore nothing will be shown in your case.

```
button#playButton {
  background: url('res/play.png');
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: button becomes larger, but no image is loaded.

Comment: did you add "" to the url?
Try using this, background: url("/res/play.png");

Comment: yeah I did it, look number2 above

Comment: If that's the case as @Dai mentioned, try opening your Chrome Dev Tool > Network. Then hit F5 button and see if the image is found successfully.

Comment: Image loaded successfully thanks. But is this no other option to load Image? When every time user uses app, open Network tab and press F5 is kind of uncomfortable thing...

Comment: If the image has been loaded, it means the url link is correct.
It would not make sense for the user to open Network tab and F5 everytime.